# DDD Aggregate boundaries one to some and not one to many between entities in one aggregate

Tags: entity, domain-driven-design, aggregation, clean-architecture

I've watched a tutorial about DDD in which it says that if I have aggregate root SnackMachine which has more than 30 child elements the child elements should be in separate aggregate. For example, SnackMachine has lots of PurshaseLog (more than 30) and it is better for PurshaseLog to be in a separate aggregate. Why is that?

Comment: Could you please add a reference to the tutorial and ideally cite the statement which promotes splitting the aggregate? There can be different motivations for that...

Comment: Domain-Driven Design in Practice By Vladimir Khorikov on pluralsight 4. Extending the bounded context with aggregates, part: How to find boundaries for aggregates

Comment: Great question - the only way you could get an accurate answer is to elaborate on your use cases which will help define your context boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for limiting the overall size of an aggregate is because you always load the full aggregate into memory and you always store the full aggregate transactionally. A very large aggregate would cause technical problems.

That said, there is no such "30 child elements" rule in aggregate design and it sounds arbitrary as a rule. For example, having fewer very large child elements could be technically worse than having 30 very light child elements. A good way of storing aggregates is as json documents, given that you'll always read and write the documents as atomic operations. If you think it this way, you'll realise that an aggregate design that implies a very large or even ever-growing child collection will eventually cause problems. A PurhaseLog sounds like an ever-growing collection.

The second part of the rule that says "put it in a separate aggregate" is also not correct. You don't create aggregates because you need to store some data and it doesn't fit into an existing aggregate. You create aggregates because you need to implement some business logic and this business logic will need some data, so you put both things together in an aggregate.

So, although what you explain in your question are things to take into consideration when designing aggregates to avoid having technological problems, I'd suggest you put your attention to the actual responsibilities of the aggregate.

In your example, what are the responsibilities of the SnackMachine? Does it really need the (full) list of PurchaseLogs? What operations will the SnackMachine expose? Let's say that it exposes PurchaseProduct(productId) and LoadProduct(productId, quantity). To execute its business logic, this aggregate would need a list of products and keep count of their available quantity, but it wouldn't need to store the purchase log. Instead, at every Purchase, it could publish an event ProductPurchased(SnackMachineId, ProductId, Date, AvailableQuantity). Then external systems could subscribe to this event. One subscriber could register the PurchaseLog for reporting purposes and another subscriber could send someone to reload the machine when the stock was lower than X.

Answer (score 3):

If PurchaseLog is not its own aggregate then it implies that it can only be retrieved or added as part of the child collection of SnackMachine.

Therefore, each time you want to add a PurchaseLog, you'd retrieve the SnackMachine with its child PurchaseLogs, add the PurchaseLog to its collection.  Then save changes on your unit of work.

Did you really need to retrieve 30+ purchase logs which are redundant for the purpose of the use case of creating a new purchase log?

**Application Layer - Option 1 (PurchaseLog is an owned entity of SnackMachine)**

```
// Retrieve the snack machine from repo, along with child purchase logs
// Assuming 30 logs, this would retrieve 31 entities from the database that
// your unit of work will start tracking.
SnackMachine snackMachine = await _snackMachineRepository.GetByIdAsync(snackMachineId);

// Ask snack machine to add a new purchase log to its collection
snackMachine.AddPurchaseLog(date, quantity);

// Update
await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**Application Layer - Option 2 (PurchaseLog is an aggregate root)**

```
// Get a snackmachine from the repo to make sure that one exists
// for the provided id.  (Only 1 entity retrieved);
SnackMachine snackMachine = await _snackMachineRepository.GetByIdAsync(snackMachineId);

// Create Purhcase log
PurchaseLog purchaseLog = new(
   snackMachine,
   date,
   quantity);

await _purchaseLogRepository.AddAsync(purchaseLog);

await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync()
```

**PurchaseLog - option 2**

```
class PurchaseLog
{
    int _snackMachineId;
    DateTimne _date;
    int _quantity;

    PurchaseLog(
        SnackMachine snackMachine,
        DateTime date,
        int quantity)
    {
        _snackMachineId = snackMachine?.Id ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(snackMachine));
        _date = date;
        _quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

The second option follows the contours of your use case more accurately and also results in a lot less i/o with the database.